# Wager must be less than balance to continue C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

So I am working on a game of craps, one aspect of the game is that the wager must be less than or equal to balance to continue (so you don't bet more than you have). Right now I have my full game I am working on, but that would be too much code to post, so I wrote out essentially what I am trying to do.

The code I am posting assumes it is a loss, but it does not subtract correctly for some reason. And in my actual game, it ignores the while function completely ie. if my balance is 20 and I bet 22 it gives me -2. I can not figure out how to make this work correctly..

```
    #include<stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    double balance = 0.0, wager = 0.0;

    balance = get_balance();
    wager = get_wager();
    checking_wager(balance, wager);
    loss(balance, wager);

    return 0;
}

double get_balance(void)
{
    double balance = 0.0;
    balance = printf("Enter your balance: ");
    scanf("%lf", &balance); 
    return balance;
}

double get_wager(void)
{
    double wager = 0.0;
    wager = printf("Enter your wager: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &wager);
    return wager;
}

double checking_wager(double balance, double wager)
{
    while (wager > balance)
    {
        printf("The wager is invalid\n");
        wager = get_wager();
    }
    return 0;
}

double loss(double balance, double wager)
{
    balance -= wager;
    printf("Balance: %.2f", balance);
    return balance;
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how I can make this work, I would really appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: first problem: `get_balance` returns an `int` to `balance` which is a `double`. Same with `get_wager`. I imagine there are compiler warnings about this.

Comment: `loss(double balance, double wager) ` ! you need also to correct return type of functions which need to be `double`.

Comment: `double checking_wager(double balance, double wager)` should be `double checking_wager(double balance, double *wager)` where inside the function you have `*wager = get_wager()`.... or have `return wager`, not `return 0`.

Comment: you guys were right, i was just getting in the habit of writing function definitions with int, thanks for catching this, I am getting this error now on my function definitons

1>c:\users\sarah\documents\a cpts 121\pa 4\testing recurrsion\testing recurrsion\test.c(32): error C2371: 'checking_wager': redefinition; different basic types
1>c:\users\sarah\documents\a cpts 121\pa 4\testing recurrsion\testing recurrsion\test.c(42): error C2371: 'loss': redefinition; different basic types

Comment: Move `main` to the bottom of the file, so it gets the correct return type and arg defs for the other functions. The other option is to add forward declarations for the functions above `main`. If you aren't already doing so, compile with `-Wall` to see if this helps

Comment: moving main to the bottom fixed the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reformat you code, now it should work.

```
int main(void)
{
    double balance = 0.0, wager = 0.0;

    balance = get_balance();
    wager = get_wager();
    checking_wager(balance, &wager);
    loss(balance, wager);

   return 0;
}

double get_balance(void)
{
    double balance = 0.0;
    balance = printf("Enter your balance: ");
    scanf("%lf", &balance);
    return balance;
}

double get_wager(void)
{
    double wager = 0.0;
    wager = printf("Enter your wager: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &wager);
    return wager;
}

double checking_wager(double balance, double *wager)
{
    while (*wager > balance)
    {
        printf("The wager is invalid\n");
        *wager = get_wager();
    }
    return 0;
 }

 double loss(double balance, double wager)
 {
     balance -= wager;
     printf("Balance: %.2f", balance);
     return balance;
 }
```

The changes I've done, is first replaced the returntypes form

```
int
```

to

```
double
```

Second and more importent, I've change the second paramter int this function

```
int checking_wager(double balance, double wager)
```

to a pointer to double

```
double checking_wager(double balance, double *wager)
```

The reason this, to return the new wager from the function.

Comment: I think this code should work, but I am getting the error on line 32 on 42 that there is a "redefintion different basic types" error

Comment: What is the codeline there exactly? Have you updated your header file too?

Comment: 31 (sorry i said 32 but i ment 31) : 'double checking_wager(double balance, double *wager)'

Comment: 41(didnt mean 42) : 'double loss(double balance, double wager)'

Comment: But I am still getting the same error with this code.. :(

Comment: It seems like moving main to the bottom fixed this problem!

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs from the definition of your `checking_wager()` function.

So from my assumption, you passed two parameters which are `balance` and `wager`, and hopefully to reinput value of `wager` in case it's greater than `balance`.

However, your code doesn't do like you'd intended, because you defined the `wager` as a **new local variable**, which doesn't share the same location as `wager` from main function.

So, the easiest fix is to change `checking_wager()'s wager` into a pointer, so that it can refers and changes value from `main()'s wager`.

```
int checking_wager(double balance, double *wager)
{
    while (*wager > balance)
    {
        printf("The wager is invalid\n");
        *wager = get_wager();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, to call it from main function, you can basically give main function's wager pointer into the checking_wager() function.

```
checking_wager(balance, &wager);
```

Hopefully that will helps.

Comment: It also doesn't return balance, which also needs to be a pointer in order to change the outer value.